# Order CollectionType in FormType with many-to-many relation

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have a relation many-to-many.
In Entity "Progetti" i have:

```
/**
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $attivita
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attivita", inversedBy="progetti",cascade={"persist", "remove" })
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="progetti_attivita",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="progetti_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="attivita_id", referencedColumnName="id")}

     * )

     */
    protected $attivita;
```

In Entity "Attività" i have:

```
/**
     *
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $progetti
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Progetti", mappedBy="attivita")

     */
    protected $progetti;
```

Ok.
The JoinTable "progetti_attivita" has "attivita_id" and "progetti_id".
Now i added a new field to the JoinTable "progetti_attivita" and i called it "position". it's an integer.

I have the ProgettiType Form:

```
$builder
            ->add('nomeProgetto')
            ->add('descProgetto')
            ->add('noteProgetto')
            ->add('attivita', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => AttivitaType::class,
                    'allow_add' => true,

            ));
```

Ok.
I have the form that display all "attività" for "progetti".

My question is:
How can i say to Form to display "attivita" ordered by "position" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your collection to be ordered then you can add the OrderBy property to your Doctrine mapping:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Attivita")
 * @OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 **/
private $attivitas;
```

An alternative approach would be to add a getAttivitaOrdered method to your Progetti entity:

```
class Progetti 
    getAttivitaOrdered() // return ordered list

->add('attivitaOrdered', CollectionType::class ...
```

Not sure if you will need a setAttivitaOrdered method or not when you post.

And your question is actually a little bit confusing.  Adding a property to your join table means that you need to use OneToMany and ManyToOne relations instead of ManyToMany.  So a few more adjustments will be needed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. the problem is that "attivita" can be in "progetti" and can have different "position". It's like a song that can in be in different album ma can have a different position by the album

Comment: Of course.  The Doctrine ManyToMany relation does not support having additional properties on the join table.  So you need to make a ProgettiAttivitia entity and establish OnToMany relations as needed.  It is all discussed in the docs.  Once this is implemented then worry about the ordering.